# Patch value to multiple formArray in Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, reactive, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

Not able to patch multiple formArray in a formGroup.

**Form**

```
 this.usersForm = this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array([
        {
          firstName: [""],
          lastName: [""],
        }
      ]),
      work: this.fb.array([
        {
          workType: [""],
          workTitle: [""],
        }
      ]),
    });
```

I have multiple formArray like these, how to patchValue to it.
I tried the below approach but it makes the code too redundant

```
const formArray = new FormArray([]);

    data.work.forEach((s) => {
      formArray.push(
        this.fb.group({
          workType: s.workType,
          workTitle: s.workTitle,
        })
      );
    });

this.usersForm.setControl("work", formArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//get form array control
let a = this.usersForm.get('work') as FormArray;

// push control in above form array
a.push(this.fb.group({
      workType: 'workType value',
      workTitle: 'workTitle value'
});
```

or if you want to use patchValue then

```
this.usersForm.patchValue(your json);
```

Comment: this approach is also redundant as I have around 10 formArray and i was looking for a generalized solution for all my formArray to patch value